PkgConfig can't find 'glib-2.0' when trying to build with CMake
I am trying to compile a program that's written in C++ by using CMake.
The contents of the CMakeLists.txt file it the code came with are:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(<redacted> C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(<redacted> src/main.cpp
        src/<redacted>.h
        src/<redacted>.h src/<redacted>.cpp
        src/<redacted>.h
        src/<redacted>.h src/<redacted>.cpp
        src/<redacted>.h src/<redacted>.cpp
        src/<redacted>.h
        src/<redacted>.h src/<redacted>.c
        src/<redacted>.h)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)


include_directories(${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(<redacted> ${GLIB_LIBRARIES} gcrypt)

When I run the command: cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles" && make in w64devkit (Or in Visual Studio, or VSCode), I get the following error:
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/Users/Jonathon/Downloads/pkg-config-lite-0.28-1_bin-win32/pkg-config-lite-0.28-1/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "0.28")
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0'
--   No package 'glib-2.0' found
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:634 (message):
  The following required packages were not found:

   - glib-2.0

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:862 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (PKG_CHECK_MODULES)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

There is a similar post here but that was on linux, and I am on Windows. Also, the solution which was found was removing a line from CMakeLists.txt, but that line isn't present in my CMakeLists.txt file.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

[Update]
I have tried installing glib by using conan, using this as the conanfile.txt:
[requires]
glib/2.78.3

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

Then, when I type the command conan install . --output-folder=build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake && cmake --build (as suggested here because I was getting an 'ERROR: Conanfile not found' when I just used conan install . --output-folder=build && cmake --build ), this is the output I get:
======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows


======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\conanfile.txt
Requirements
    bzip2/1.0.8#457c272f7da34cb9c67456dd217d36c4 - Cache
    glib/2.78.3#0cd1865c8603d90b3bc5858065e16d01 - Cache
    libffi/3.4.4#35eb63842b505824b70aedc1baefc916 - Cache
    libgettext/0.22#2c87563d7a69544dd9379f038aca3b0b - Cache
    libiconv/1.17#73fefc1b696e069df90fd1d18aa63edd - Cache
    pcre2/10.42#a7a2c122056510509a7525c83d6a6695 - Cache
    zlib/1.3.1#f52e03ae3d251dec704634230cd806a2 - Cache
Build requirements
    autoconf/2.71#f9307992909d7fb3df459340f1932809 - Cache
    automake/1.16.5#058bda3e21c36c9aa8425daf3c1faf50 - Cache
    m4/1.4.19#b38ced39a01e31fef5435bc634461fd2 - Cache
    meson/1.2.2#04bdfb85d665c82b08a3510aee3ffd19 - Cache
    msys2/cci.latest#5a31efa2bde593541fd5ac3bcc50c01c - Cache
    ninja/1.11.1#77587f8c8318662ac8e5a7867eb4be21 - Cache
    pkgconf/2.0.3#f996677e96e61e6552d85e83756c328b - Cache
Resolved version ranges
    zlib/[>=1.2.11 <2]: zlib/1.3.1

======== Computing necessary packages ========
Requirements
    bzip2/1.0.8#457c272f7da34cb9c67456dd217d36c4:67bfcb7b4b78262b9d05495e479dcd92f747316b#cea9c0f0dfa41e83aebd5d39c5a5cbf3 - Cache
    glib/2.78.3#0cd1865c8603d90b3bc5858065e16d01:750e9c8cf560085c96c0fa42531c45c18af8be50#29d02404508c39a0803c3bee40426924 - Cache
    libffi/3.4.4#35eb63842b505824b70aedc1baefc916:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#37e6c892e9418389fcf21227e9c1ae6b - Cache
    libgettext/0.22#2c87563d7a69544dd9379f038aca3b0b:55052839d1d508208c0cd4c7594a7001c70287d1#bea6a5629dc31a80b4d489e5ef163ec4 - Cache
    libiconv/1.17#73fefc1b696e069df90fd1d18aa63edd:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#9ef92719f5c05dca2f0dbb46f50d3f8d - Cache
    pcre2/10.42#a7a2c122056510509a7525c83d6a6695:1bbffc30d8479a890917ef6674ab5e5f3c5b2036#d6a7c0162d1450645a9d56832ca25ae6 - Cache
    zlib/1.3.1#f52e03ae3d251dec704634230cd806a2:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#20d10b761ec15eed7a1d61c86bc7415a - Cache
Build requirements
Skipped binaries
    autoconf/2.71, automake/1.16.5, m4/1.4.19, meson/1.2.2, msys2/cci.latest, ninja/1.11.1, pkgconf/2.0.3

======== Installing packages ========
bzip2/1.0.8: Already installed! (1 of 7)
zlib/1.3.1: Already installed! (2 of 7)
libiconv/1.17: Already installed! (3 of 7)
libffi/3.4.4: Already installed! (4 of 7)
pcre2/10.42: Already installed! (5 of 7)
pcre2/10.42: Appending PATH environment variable: C:\Users\Jonathon\.conan2\p\pcre2e09694aa47719\p\bin
libgettext/0.22: Already installed! (6 of 7)
glib/2.78.3: Already installed! (7 of 7)
WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that will be removed in Conan 2.X:
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.names' used in: zlib/1.3.1, bzip2/1.0.8, pcre2/10.42, libiconv/1.17, libgettext/0.22
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.build_modules' used in: bzip2/1.0.8
WARN: deprecated:     'env_info' used in: pcre2/10.42, libiconv/1.17, bzip2/1.0.8, glib/2.78.3

======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.txt: Writing generators to C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeDeps necessary find_package() and targets for your CMakeLists.txt
    find_package(glib)
    target_link_libraries(... glib::glib)
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.txt: Preset 'conan-default' added to CMakePresets.json. Invoke it manually using 'cmake --preset conan-default' if using CMake>=3.23
conanfile.txt: If your CMake version is not compatible with CMakePresets (<3.23) call cmake like: 'cmake <path> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build\conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: CMakePresets.json
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: ..\CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.txt: Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.txt: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
Install finished successfully
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:927 (message):
  None of the required 'glib-2.0' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (pkg_search_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Now, glib version 2.78.3 is installed, because that's the latest version available from conan. The earliest version available from conan is 2.65.0, so when I tried changing the conanfile to try and get version 2.0.0, it didn't work. Also, version 2.0.0 is from 2002 and I highly doubt that the project I'm trying to compile was using that because it was made last year.
When I went back to the CMakeLists.txt file and changed this line:
pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)
to pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.78.3), then ran the conan install . --output-folder=build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake && cmake --build command again, I get this output:
======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows


======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\conanfile.txt
Requirements
    bzip2/1.0.8#457c272f7da34cb9c67456dd217d36c4 - Cache
    glib/2.78.3#0cd1865c8603d90b3bc5858065e16d01 - Cache
    libffi/3.4.4#35eb63842b505824b70aedc1baefc916 - Cache
    libgettext/0.22#2c87563d7a69544dd9379f038aca3b0b - Cache
    libiconv/1.17#73fefc1b696e069df90fd1d18aa63edd - Cache
    pcre2/10.42#a7a2c122056510509a7525c83d6a6695 - Cache
    zlib/1.3.1#f52e03ae3d251dec704634230cd806a2 - Cache
Build requirements
    autoconf/2.71#f9307992909d7fb3df459340f1932809 - Cache
    automake/1.16.5#058bda3e21c36c9aa8425daf3c1faf50 - Cache
    m4/1.4.19#b38ced39a01e31fef5435bc634461fd2 - Cache
    meson/1.2.2#04bdfb85d665c82b08a3510aee3ffd19 - Cache
    msys2/cci.latest#5a31efa2bde593541fd5ac3bcc50c01c - Cache
    ninja/1.11.1#77587f8c8318662ac8e5a7867eb4be21 - Cache
    pkgconf/2.0.3#f996677e96e61e6552d85e83756c328b - Cache
Resolved version ranges
    zlib/[>=1.2.11 <2]: zlib/1.3.1

======== Computing necessary packages ========
Requirements
    bzip2/1.0.8#457c272f7da34cb9c67456dd217d36c4:67bfcb7b4b78262b9d05495e479dcd92f747316b#cea9c0f0dfa41e83aebd5d39c5a5cbf3 - Cache
    glib/2.78.3#0cd1865c8603d90b3bc5858065e16d01:750e9c8cf560085c96c0fa42531c45c18af8be50#29d02404508c39a0803c3bee40426924 - Cache
    libffi/3.4.4#35eb63842b505824b70aedc1baefc916:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#37e6c892e9418389fcf21227e9c1ae6b - Cache
    libgettext/0.22#2c87563d7a69544dd9379f038aca3b0b:55052839d1d508208c0cd4c7594a7001c70287d1#bea6a5629dc31a80b4d489e5ef163ec4 - Cache
    libiconv/1.17#73fefc1b696e069df90fd1d18aa63edd:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#9ef92719f5c05dca2f0dbb46f50d3f8d - Cache
    pcre2/10.42#a7a2c122056510509a7525c83d6a6695:1bbffc30d8479a890917ef6674ab5e5f3c5b2036#d6a7c0162d1450645a9d56832ca25ae6 - Cache
    zlib/1.3.1#f52e03ae3d251dec704634230cd806a2:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#20d10b761ec15eed7a1d61c86bc7415a - Cache
Build requirements
Skipped binaries
    autoconf/2.71, automake/1.16.5, m4/1.4.19, meson/1.2.2, msys2/cci.latest, ninja/1.11.1, pkgconf/2.0.3

======== Installing packages ========
bzip2/1.0.8: Already installed! (1 of 7)
zlib/1.3.1: Already installed! (2 of 7)
libiconv/1.17: Already installed! (3 of 7)
libffi/3.4.4: Already installed! (4 of 7)
pcre2/10.42: Already installed! (5 of 7)
pcre2/10.42: Appending PATH environment variable: C:\Users\Jonathon\.conan2\p\pcre2e09694aa47719\p\bin
libgettext/0.22: Already installed! (6 of 7)
glib/2.78.3: Already installed! (7 of 7)
WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that will be removed in Conan 2.X:
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.names' used in: bzip2/1.0.8, libiconv/1.17, libgettext/0.22, zlib/1.3.1, pcre2/10.42
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.build_modules' used in: bzip2/1.0.8
WARN: deprecated:     'env_info' used in: glib/2.78.3, bzip2/1.0.8, libiconv/1.17, pcre2/10.42

======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.txt: Writing generators to C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeDeps necessary find_package() and targets for your CMakeLists.txt
    find_package(glib)
    target_link_libraries(... glib::glib)
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.txt: Preset 'conan-default' added to CMakePresets.json. Invoke it manually using 'cmake --preset conan-default' if using CMake>=3.23
conanfile.txt: If your CMake version is not compatible with CMakePresets (<3.23) call cmake like: 'cmake <path> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build\conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: CMakePresets.json
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: ..\CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.txt: Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.txt: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
Install finished successfully
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:927 (message):
  None of the required 'glib-2.0' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (pkg_search_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build>cd ..

C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main>conan install . --output-folder=build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake && cmake --build

======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows


======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\conanfile.txt
Requirements
    bzip2/1.0.8#457c272f7da34cb9c67456dd217d36c4 - Cache
    glib/2.78.3#0cd1865c8603d90b3bc5858065e16d01 - Cache
    libffi/3.4.4#35eb63842b505824b70aedc1baefc916 - Cache
    libgettext/0.22#2c87563d7a69544dd9379f038aca3b0b - Cache
    libiconv/1.17#73fefc1b696e069df90fd1d18aa63edd - Cache
    pcre2/10.42#a7a2c122056510509a7525c83d6a6695 - Cache
    zlib/1.3.1#f52e03ae3d251dec704634230cd806a2 - Cache
Build requirements
    autoconf/2.71#f9307992909d7fb3df459340f1932809 - Cache
    automake/1.16.5#058bda3e21c36c9aa8425daf3c1faf50 - Cache
    m4/1.4.19#b38ced39a01e31fef5435bc634461fd2 - Cache
    meson/1.2.2#04bdfb85d665c82b08a3510aee3ffd19 - Cache
    msys2/cci.latest#5a31efa2bde593541fd5ac3bcc50c01c - Cache
    ninja/1.11.1#77587f8c8318662ac8e5a7867eb4be21 - Cache
    pkgconf/2.0.3#f996677e96e61e6552d85e83756c328b - Cache
Resolved version ranges
    zlib/[>=1.2.11 <2]: zlib/1.3.1

======== Computing necessary packages ========
Requirements
    bzip2/1.0.8#457c272f7da34cb9c67456dd217d36c4:67bfcb7b4b78262b9d05495e479dcd92f747316b#cea9c0f0dfa41e83aebd5d39c5a5cbf3 - Cache
    glib/2.78.3#0cd1865c8603d90b3bc5858065e16d01:750e9c8cf560085c96c0fa42531c45c18af8be50#29d02404508c39a0803c3bee40426924 - Cache
    libffi/3.4.4#35eb63842b505824b70aedc1baefc916:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#37e6c892e9418389fcf21227e9c1ae6b - Cache
    libgettext/0.22#2c87563d7a69544dd9379f038aca3b0b:55052839d1d508208c0cd4c7594a7001c70287d1#bea6a5629dc31a80b4d489e5ef163ec4 - Cache
    libiconv/1.17#73fefc1b696e069df90fd1d18aa63edd:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#9ef92719f5c05dca2f0dbb46f50d3f8d - Cache
    pcre2/10.42#a7a2c122056510509a7525c83d6a6695:1bbffc30d8479a890917ef6674ab5e5f3c5b2036#d6a7c0162d1450645a9d56832ca25ae6 - Cache
    zlib/1.3.1#f52e03ae3d251dec704634230cd806a2:7bfde258ff4f62f75668d0896dbddedaa7480a0f#20d10b761ec15eed7a1d61c86bc7415a - Cache
Build requirements
Skipped binaries
    autoconf/2.71, automake/1.16.5, m4/1.4.19, meson/1.2.2, msys2/cci.latest, ninja/1.11.1, pkgconf/2.0.3

======== Installing packages ========
bzip2/1.0.8: Already installed! (1 of 7)
zlib/1.3.1: Already installed! (2 of 7)
libiconv/1.17: Already installed! (3 of 7)
libffi/3.4.4: Already installed! (4 of 7)
pcre2/10.42: Already installed! (5 of 7)
pcre2/10.42: Appending PATH environment variable: C:\Users\Jonathon\.conan2\p\pcre2e09694aa47719\p\bin
libgettext/0.22: Already installed! (6 of 7)
glib/2.78.3: Already installed! (7 of 7)
WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that will be removed in Conan 2.X:
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.names' used in: pcre2/10.42, libiconv/1.17, bzip2/1.0.8, zlib/1.3.1, libgettext/0.22
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.build_modules' used in: bzip2/1.0.8
WARN: deprecated:     'env_info' used in: pcre2/10.42, bzip2/1.0.8, glib/2.78.3, libiconv/1.17

======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.txt: Writing generators to C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeDeps necessary find_package() and targets for your CMakeLists.txt
    find_package(glib)
    target_link_libraries(... glib::glib)
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.txt: Preset 'conan-default' added to CMakePresets.json. Invoke it manually using 'cmake --preset conan-default' if using CMake>=3.23
conanfile.txt: If your CMake version is not compatible with CMakePresets (<3.23) call cmake like: 'cmake <path> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Jonathon\source\tlsdump-main\tlsdump-main\build\conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: CMakePresets.json
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: ..\CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.txt: Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.txt: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
Install finished successfully
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.78.3'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:927 (message):
  None of the required 'glib-2.78.3' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (pkg_search_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

And this really doesn't make sense to me, because when it's installing packages, it clearly shows this line in bright green: glib/2.78.3: Already installed! (7 of 7), then shortly after, it still shows:
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.78.3'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:927 (message):
  None of the required 'glib-2.78.3' found

So I really have no idea what's going on. glib is clearly installed but the cmake pkgconfig still isn't finding it for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Have you installed glib? What is output of pkg-config glib-2.0?

The output is:
pkg-config: could not find package 'glib-2.0'
I tried following the advice from here but installing GTK didn't solve the problem

Also, I just edited the original post to include some things I've tried so far i.e. installing glib using conan, which still hasn't solved the problem of the pkgmanager not finding it. I have tried everything that I can think of, and there may be more things to try but this is my very first time compiling a C++ project at all, so it's also my first time using cmake.

And, the output of pkg-config glib-2.0 is still pkg-config: could not find package 'glib-2.0'

Have you considered using MSYS2? I've just tried it: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glib2 to install glib, then pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0 prints the flags.

Thanks, I will try it when I get home and let you know if it works. Whatever works is the most important thing, but I'm curious yo find out what's actually causing the problem.

I've never used any of these C++ build tools before so I have no idea what the expected behaviour is for any of them. All I have is my knowledge from other (higher level) programming languages like python & C#. I'm normally good at solving problems but C++ is something I have no experience with.

I think pkg-config reads some env variables to know where to look for libraries (PKG_CONFIG_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR). It's also supposed to have default directories, but I'm not sure what are those for the standalone version you downloaded. That's why I always suggest MSYS2 in those situations: they configure the tools they ship to work together. You install a library and it shows up in pkg-config and CMake with zero configuration (if it's not obvious, you need to install all tools from them: CMake, pkg-config, gcc, and glib). This is the experience you'd have on Linux out of the box.

Great information, thank you. I'm actually a linux user normally but this has to be on windows. Also, please write an answer instead of a comment, and if your solution works then I'll award the bounty to you

Most likely PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR is wrong. That would explain why in this post (which has the same error message as me), the solution was removing a line from CMakeLists.txt which was related to that exact env variable

Also to clarify, which of these two is the way it's supposed to work? (1) glib or any package gets downloaded and instealled directly into the project which needs to br compiled, and nowhere else. Or (2) that there's some kind of global directory where you install packages like glib, and then it gets added to the project? I guess the first one makes more sense, but I don't know.

MSYS2 installs globally. It operates like a linux distribution would (and uses Arch's pacman to manage packages). I'm not sure how Conan does it.

Summarizing my explanation in the comments:
It should be possible to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to point it to the glib installation. pkg-config looks for libraries in directories specified in this variable (and some others).
But instead of doing manual configuration, I'd rather recommend using MSYS2. Use it to install all tools you need: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pkgconf mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glib2.
Open MSYS2 terminal and compile inside of it (to have the correct env variables set). Verify that the terminal prompt says UCRT64 in magenta text (What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?).
You can try pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0 and see it finds the library.

Thanks for your answer. While it solves the problem of pkg-config not finding glib-2.0, which is the question I asked there are still more steps to be able to compile it, which I'm still figuring out. When I installed those packages in MSYS2 then typed the command pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0,  it did find it. Then, I tried building yesterday and it said it was successful but I can't find any binaries, and the directory where it says the build files were written to doesn't contain any .exe files or any executables at all. Probably I've misunderstood something again.

Also this is a quote from the MSYS2 docs: "When building projects for Windows with CMake (as opposed to building projects that are going to run in MSYS2 posix emulation runtime) make sure to install the MinGW version of CMake, i.e. installing e.g. mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake". Does this mean that the ucrt environment builds will only work from within the MSYS2 terminal?

PS. You don't have to answer since you already answered the original question, but I'd appreciate if you can still clarify that.

@JonathonQuick "will only work from within the MSYS2 terminal?" No, they worded it poorly. What they're saying is to not install cmake, but rather mingw-...-cmake. Which one of the latter, ucrt or not, doesn't really matter. (The former belongs to the "MSYS" environment, see the second link in my answer and/or https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments). As for where your exe files are, they should be there. Try searching in the subdirectories, or ask a whole separate question with all the details.

"it said it was successful but I can't find any binaries, and the directory where it says the build files were written to doesn't contain any .exe files or any executables at all." - Running cmake only configures the project. For build it run cmake --build from the build directory.

@JonathonQuick ^
